# Como criar uma paginação para Attachments no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Bom, se alguém souber como criar uma paginação para uma página que exibe as imagens adicionadas no WordPress, eu agradeceria a ajuda, o código que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    $args = array(
                  'posts_per_page' => '30',
                  'post_type' => 'attachment',
                  'paged' => $paged
);

    $myposts = get_posts($args);        
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>



<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
global $post;
    foreach( $myposts as $post )  {
        setup_postdata( $post );

echo '<articlep>
  <thumb>
     <a href="';
         the_permalink();
echo '">';
         echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID());
echo '</a>
   </thumb>
   <ttitle>
     <a href="';
        the_permalink();
echo '">';
        the_title();
echo '</a></ttitle></articlep>';


                }




            endwhile;

     $big = 999999999; 
    paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ), 
                        'format' => '&paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
   )); 
?>
```

Ali no final eu testei um modelo de paginação que encontrei no codex do WordPress, mas não funcionou.
Se quiser ver como está agora o link é esse: http://g-y.one/erus

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pra quem está precisando fazer uma galeria igual a minha o único jeito que achei para realizar essa paginação foi com um plugin chamando "Media Library Assistant", ai só precisei trocar todo aquele código por:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode ('
    [mla_gallery post_parent=all numberposts=30 mla_caption="{+title+}" orderby=dateDESC]
');
?>




<div>

<?php echo do_shortcode ('
[mla_gallery post_parent=all numberposts=30 mla_output=paginate_links]
');
?>
</div>
```